# How to JSON serialize objects that contain a file?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to retrieve `Story` together with the associated `story_media` from my DRF backend. `Story_Media` contains both data and files and comes as a list. This means a single `Story` can have multiple `Story_Media` objects (`Story` is FK in `story_media`).

However, when I want to return the litst of `Story_Media` objects, it seems that they are not serializable. So my question is, how do I JSON serialize objects that contain a file?

> TypeError: Object of type Story_Media is not JSON serializable

```
class StoryRetrieveSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    story_media = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_story_media')

    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields =  ('title', 'story_media')

    def get_story_media(self, story):
        return Story_Media.objects.filter(story=story.id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a serializer for `Story_Media`, pass the objects of your **queryset** to it with `many=True` and return serializer data

For ex:

```
def get_story_media(self, story):
        qs = Story_Media.objects.filter(story=story.id)
        serializer = StoryMediaSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

Comment: Note: the default naming for a field with`SerializerMethodField` is 'get_<field_name>` so you don't have to pass a name to it unless you want add a different name

Comment: Thanks for the answer i will check it tomorrow!